# cortar un texto CSS

Tags: css

¿Cómo puedo cortar un texto de una linea? me sirve por cantidad de palabras o por alguna palabra clave para determinar el corte.

**Ejemplo 1:** United States - Florida
donde ''-'' es la palabra que determina el recorte
Resultado: United States

**Ejemplo 2:** United States Florida
Tomar las primeras dos palabras
Resultado: United States

Probe con text-overflow, la cosa es que termina haciéndome un corte como:
United States Flo

O si no me hace un salto de linea más o menos así: (Me serviría si pudiese eliminar la segunda linea)
United States
Florida

**Nota:** El texto no esta especificado, es decir no es un solo texto predeterminado ya que se aplica a los titulos de cada pais/estado.

**Nota 2:** Sólo estoy usando CSS puro (No HTML) ya que es una modificación visual a una extensión de google chrome.

Comment: Solo con CSS no creo que sea posible, en este caso es necesario usar JavaScript para poder modificar correctamente los textos. Usar el método [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) te podría funcionar.

Comment: cada línea está en un contenedor diferente? onda un li o un p o un div?

Comment: Se puede hacer que al desbordar el texto me haga un salto de linea y al mismo tiempo borrar la segunda linea?
De poder hacerse de esa forma no me importaría agregar espacios para separar el texto restante hasta que caiga en la segunda linea.

Ejemplo: United States           Florida
Resultado: United States

Answer (score 1):

Pude resolverlo.

```
.div {
        display: block;
        text-overflow: clip;
        overflow: hidden;         /* Para poder hacer salto de linea */
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        font-size: 0vw;
    }

.div::firstline {
        font-size: 2vw;
    }
```

Apliqué margenes y max-width para ajustar los limites del texto, no era exactamente lo que buscaba pero estoy satisfecho.